# Proof of application equality in coq

Tags: functional-programming, coq, proof

I have a sequence of applications in that way (f (f (f x))), being f an arbitrary function and any applications numbers sequences.
I want to prove that f (x y) and (x (f y)), x = (f f f ...) and y = any value, it's equal.
I need that proof in the code below:

```
Fixpoint r_nat {A : Type} (a : nat) : A -> (A -> A) -> A :=
  match a with
    |S n => fun (x0 : A) (a0 : A -> A) => r_nat n (a0 x0) a0
    |0 => fun (x0 : A) (_ : A -> A) => x0
  end. 


Theorem homomo_nat : forall {T} (f : T -> T) (h : T) (x : nat), (r_nat x (f h) f) = f ((r_nat x) h f) .
compute.
??.
Qed.
```

I try unfolding and refining but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the argument `(x:nat)` before `(h:T)`.  That makes the induction hypothesis stronger - it holds for *all* `h`.  Then the proof is simply:

```
Theorem homomo_nat : forall {T} (f : T -> T) (x:nat) (h : T), (r_nat x (f h) f) = f ((r_nat x) h f) .
Proof.
  induction x.
  reflexivity.
  intros. apply IHx.
Qed.
```

You can also "move the arguments around" with tactics to keep your original theorem if you prefer that...  Start with `intros; generalize dependent h.`

Comment: I tried induction by x, but my hypothesis was a little "weak", with your example works well, thank u.

Answer (score 1):

This should be solvable by an induction on the `x`, the number of times `f` is applied.